# Can't edit the widgets sidebar or footer

Tags: widgets, sidebar, footer

Why can't I edit my widgets sidebar ?

[image: here is the example]

website can be found [here](https://www.vgopromo.com).

Comment: Your footer and sidebar must not have been implemented using widgets. You will need to ask your theme’s author how to edit these areas.

Comment: I want to do it myself not ask and since author support is expired

Comment: We’ll it’s impossible to answer without knowledge of the theme and third party themes are off topic here.